# Referencing a ReactJS object property using a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, properties, conditional-statements

I am trying to reference a JS object property using a string on a React Component so that I can remove a repetitive conditional statement.
This is my current render function:

```js
render() {
    const { USD, GBP, EUR } = this.props.bpi;
    const { currency } = this.state;
    console.log(currency);
    let list = '';
    if (this.state.currency === currency) {
      list = (
        <li className='list-group-item'>
          Bitcoin rate for {USD.description}:{' '}
          <span className='badge badge-primary'>{USD.code}</span>{' '}
          <strong>{USD.rate}</strong>
        </li>
      );
    } else if (this.state.currency === 'GBP') {
      list = (
        <li className='list-group-item'>
          Bitcoin rate for {GBP.description}:{' '}
          <span className='badge badge-primary'>{GBP.code}</span>{' '}
          <strong>{GBP.rate}</strong>
        </li>
      );
    } else if (this.state.currency === 'EUR') {
      list = (
        <li className='list-group-item'>
          Bitcoin rate for {EUR.description}:{' '}
          <span className='badge badge-primary'>{EUR.code}</span>{' '}
          <strong>{EUR.rate}</strong>
        </li>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({ currency: e.target.value })}
          className='form-control'
        >
          <option value='USD'>USD</option>
          <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
          <option value='EUR'>EUR</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <ul className='list-group'>{list}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Notice that in my code above, I repeated the list 3 times to find set the correct object property.
lets say I have this "currency" object:

```
const currency = {
  USD: {
     description: "This is USD",
     code: "USD",
     rate: "5.6",
  },
  GBP: {
     description: "This is GBP",
     code: "GBP",
     rate: "6",
  },
  EUR: {
     description: "This is EUR",
     code: "EUR",
     rate: "8",
  }
}
```

How do I set the string in my currency state as a property value of the object so that I can just declare one list without the repetitive conditioning? What I want to achieve is this part of the code:

```
if (this.state.currency === currency) {
  list = (
    <li className='list-group-item'>
      Bitcoin rate for {USD.description}:{' '}
      <span className='badge badge-primary'>{USD.code}</span>{' '}
      <strong>{USD.rate}</strong>
    </li>
  );
} else if (this.state.currency === 'GBP') {
  list = (
    <li className='list-group-item'>
      Bitcoin rate for {GBP.description}:{' '}
      <span className='badge badge-primary'>{GBP.code}</span>{' '}
      <strong>{GBP.rate}</strong>
    </li>
  );
} else if (this.state.currency === 'EUR') {
  list = (
    <li className='list-group-item'>
      Bitcoin rate for {EUR.description}:{' '}
      <span className='badge badge-primary'>{EUR.code}</span>{' '}
      <strong>{EUR.rate}</strong>
    </li>
  );
}
```

And convert it into something like this (maybe i dont actually know):

```
list = (
    <li className='list-group-item'>
      Bitcoin rate for {currency.description}:{' '}
      <span className='badge badge-primary'>{currency.code}</span>{' '}
      <strong>{currency.rate}</strong>
    </li>
  );
```

Comment: How about a single variable instead of separate USD/GBP/EUR? `const CUR = this.props.bpi[this.state.currency];`

Comment: Thank you I was stuck in a deadend I guess @David784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @David784 for the realization of calling it as a single object. Here is my final render method:

```
  render() {
const CUR = this.props.bpi[this.state.currency];
let list = (
  <li className='list-group-item'>
    Bitcoin rate for {CUR.description}:{' '}
    <span className='badge badge-primary'>{CUR.code}</span>{' '}
    <strong>{CUR.rate}</strong>
  </li>
);
return (
  <div>
    <select
      onChange={(e) => this.setState({ currency: e.target.value })}
      className='form-control'
    >
      <option value='USD'>USD</option>
      <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
      <option value='EUR'>EUR</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <ul className='list-group'>{list}</ul>
  </div>
);
}
```

with this as the emphasis

```
const CUR = this.props.bpi[this.state.currency];
    let list = (
      <li className='list-group-item'>
        Bitcoin rate for {CUR.description}:{' '}
        <span className='badge badge-primary'>{CUR.code}</span>{' '}
        <strong>{CUR.rate}</strong>
      </li>
    );
```